# Ubercart uc_cart_get_contents get data from standard class

Tags: php, drupal, ubercart

I'm writing a custom module for one of my projects and I'm having a bit of an issue.  What I'm trying to do is get a piece of data from uc_cart_get_contents() into a variable so that I can use it in a calculation:

Here's my var_export:

```
array ( )array ( 0 => stdClass::__set_state(array( 'cart_item_id' => '5', 'cart_id' => '1', 'nid' => '9', 'qty' => '10', 'changed' => '1287074120', 'data' => array ( 'attributes' => array ( 3 => '4', ), 'shippable' => '1', 'restrict_qty' => '0', 'module' => 'uc_product', ), 'title' => 'Chicago Canyon', 'vid' => '9', 'cost' => 1.16, 'price' => 11.16, 'weight' => 0, 'module' => 'uc_product', 'model' => 'chicago-canyon-p-card-p-env', )), )
```

But what if I want to put the model of each item in the cart into a variable, and based upon that variable adjust the item's price.

If it was an array I would do this:

```
$items= uc_cart_get_contents();

$model = $items[model];
```

but that doesn't work, it's a std class.  I'm so so lost.  Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your asking how to access object propertiers you do so like this:

```
$model = $items->model;
```

Comment: that doesn't seem to work.  I tried it, but when I try to echo out the variable nothing comes out.  But no error is thrown though.

Comment: Actually I just tried using $item from uc_attribute_calc_cart_item($op, &$item) {
and the echo worked, the data got pulled through.  so I think you were correct on the syntax and there's something up with that specific function.  Thank you very much for your answer!

Answer (score 2):

for starters, uc_cart_get_contents() returns an array of objects. so, if you did:

```
$items=uc_cart_get_contents();
```

you would have to iterate over $items, and then get the specific data elements you want from each item.

for example:

```
$items = uc_cart_get_contents();
foreach ($items as $item)
{
  $model = $item->model;
  // whatever ... 
}
```

hope that helps